# Some non-game specific questions have specific games as answers. Should these questions get game-specific tags?

Tags: discussion, tagging

Some non-game specific questions have specific games as answers. Should these questions get game-specific tags with each new game-specific answer? I think people interested in a specific game stand a good chance of being interested in such questions. For example, this one:

[Which boardgames need expansion sets before they work properly?](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/2410/which-boardgames-need-expansion-sets-before-they-work-properly)

Should it be tagged with Civilization, Settlers-of-Catan, Citadels, St-Petersburg, Carcassone, Agricola, Alhambra, and Cosmic-Encounter?

Answer (score 4):

**No**,

Tagging is not a replacement for search.  The site has very good search capability, anyone searching for those games will find them with no trouble.

Comment: I was thinking tracking, not search. I use tag tracking on my favorite few games which causes a light blue background behind questions. Very helpful to me for staying focused on what's of interest to me. Also - at times I'll go into e-mail mode where I just receive emails on the questions of interest to me, which again will be related to my favorite tags. The question I cited was a perfect example of a question I would love to be notified about (I'm an owner of the basic Carcassone game and Settlers with just the Seafarers expansion).

Comment: Also, there's a limit of five tags per question.